# Correct NGINX rewrite rule for static files

Tags: css, nginx, try-catch

I want to create a NGINX rewrite rule for static CSS and JavaScript files.

E.G Browser request: `www.website.com/staticfiles/generatedhashhere/css/file.css`

Nginx shoold look to: `/staticfiles/css/file.css`

I want to exclude one subdirectory path.

Is it possible to write rule with NGINX try_files?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I think you are making it more complex than it needs to be. Instead of using a try_files statement for this, it would be easier to simply set up location blocks for CSS and javascript files with the directory configured for each one.

Example:

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {

root /staticfiles/css/;

}
```

If you want it to be a rewrite, then replace root statement with

`rewrite ^/staticfiles/generatedhashhere/css/(.*)$ /staticfiles/generatedhashhere/css/$;`

Comment: Does this solution have any downsides when it comes to nginx performance?